# Expo BarCodeScanner freezes (better said, the camera) when leaving the app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this BarCodeScanner from Expo placed in a tab:

```
return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
      }}
    >
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        barCodeTypes={[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.ean13]}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />

      {scanned && (
        <Button title={"Tap to Scan Again"} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

When scanned, I'm redirecting to a page like so:

```
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    props.navigation.navigate("EanProduct", {
      ean: data,
    });
  };
```

It works fine. The problem is, when I leave the app via Homebutton and go back into the app, the camera is frozen. The app **has not crashed**, I can navigate around, but the **camera is frozen**.

Is there a work-around to wake the camera back up? Or why is this happening at all? I tried to listen to navigation changes to reload the screen with didFocus for the tabbar

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const navFocusListener = props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      //console.log("reload");
    });

    return () => {
      navFocusListener.remove();
    };
  }, [props.navigation]);
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue: I have two separate components using the BarCodeScanner. Switching from A to B is fine. Switching back from B to A, however, the camera view in A is frozen. B is not. No matter how much I switch back and forth, A is always frozen, B seems to work fine.

Apparently this has been an issue for years. I haven't seen any update or response from anyone on the Expo team about this.

**UPDATE**:

I posted the link to the issue I created in a comment below but I'll post it [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9139) too, for easy access.

This appears to be a bug in iOS, not in Expo.

This [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@oscaryuen/barcodescanner-camera-freezes) demonstrates the workaround (*essentially, we have to manually unmount the BarCodeScanner/Camera component*). I can confirm that this works for me on my project.

The Expo documentation for both BarCodeScanner and Camera have been updated to callout that these components must be manually unmounted before another component can use them.

Comment: Hello @bsgbryan, please take a look the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide. It is not useful at all to post an answer that does not answer the original question. Instead consider upvoting the question or [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: I filed a bug report with Expo about this. Here's the [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9139) if you want to follow it for progress updates.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, @piraces. There is no resolution to this issue as it is a bug within the Expo project. The only step available is to file a bug report - which I did. What would be the best way to link that bug report here so that anyone else who has a similar issue can find it?

Comment: I'm happy to delete my answer and re-post it in whatever form is most helpful

Comment: Awesome @bsgbryan! Knowing that it's a bug, you can just leave your answer with your issue and the link to the bug report making it clear its a problem of the library

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if it helps but my issue was somehow fixed when I actually built the standalone app. Maybe it's the same for your issue.